# How to route outgoing traffic to one IP to another IP?

Tags: linux, iptables

I currently have a server that's about to go down.  I have a deployed application which unfortunately connect to it by IP.

How would I proceed if I wanted to run a script on the client machines so that their outgoing request to the old IP instead go to the new one?

I'm looking for some way through the command line to instruct the local machine to take outgoing traffic to ip_1 and send it to ip_2 instead.

The application can't be modified so the changes have to be external to the application.  (iptables?)  I'm hoping to push a bootup script on the clients to run the ip routing command.

(We have a domain name in place to avoid those kind of issues but some of our earlier deployments don't use it.)

Comment: Hello and welcome to the U&L stack exchange site! Please review the [Help Center](https://unix.stackexchange.com/help) to get information on how to best post to this site. Where are you trying to change the IP that the application points to? [Please edit you post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/479425/edit) to add this additional context. Can the application be told to point to a different IP? Can the new server be given the IP of the old server when it is down? Is it possible to use a proxy that the client applications can point to to avoid this situation in the future?

Comment: We can't keep our IP, our provider is losing the IP block and apparently can't work out anything so that our IP remains in our control.  

I updated the question with more context let me know if it is sufficient.

Comment: Thank you for the the additional context, If the application cannot be modified then how will the application know to use the alternate IP address? It will help to know if the application is running on clients or a server and if the server routing the traffic is in the same network or not. What does the network look like in the most basic of terms?

Comment: I have a server machine (ip_1), running a service.

I have a bunch of client machines running an application which connects to ip_1 for the service.  The application binary refers the ip directly and cannot be changed.

ip_1 is going down and I need the client machines to connect to ip_2 instead, and I can't modify the application, so I need the ip_1 -> ip_2 routing to happen somewhere in the network layer.

Comment: The service is an update service.  I can't modify the application but I can add / modify scripts which will be executed prior to the execution of the application.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easiest approach is likely to use iptables NAT:

```
iptables -t nat -A OUTPUT -d old-ip -p tcp --dport some-port -j DNAT --to-destination new-ip
```

should do that. You can use any of the normal iptables selectors to match the right traffic; I picked IP address, protocol (tcp), and port. You definitely want to limit it as much as possible; what if the new owners of that IP address put it to use as some other service you depend on from the client?

Other than that, you'd need to build some sort of tunnel (basically any type will do), then having built a private network, you can claim whatever IP address you want (on that private network), regardless of what the Internet thinks. In particular, you could route your old IP address over the tunnel. I'd only go this approach if its some weird (non-TCP/UDP) protocol you can't easily NAT.

Comment: Side question (is that allowed? sorry if not) :

Can the destination ip be a domain name or does DNS resolution occur prior to this in the chain of events?